# Algorithms - Combinations and Permutations

Tags: algorithm, performance, permutation, combinations

A hwk question and apparently also a common interview question I'm having trouble with:

"**Write an algorithm (pseudocode) that prints out all the subsets of three elements of a set of n elements.**  The elements of this set are stored in a list that is the input to the algorithm."

So for example if S = {1,2,3,4} the algorithm would print out these four combinations:

123
124
134
234

Can anyone offer their thoughts / a solution?

Comment: possible duplication of [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Comment: Not a dupe, combinations and permutations are different things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recursively:

```
def subset (prefix, list, count):
    if count is 0:
        print prefix
        return
    for each element in list:
        subset (prefix & element, list beyond element, count - 1)

subset ("", {1,2,3,4}, 3)
```

A Python proof of concept:

```
def subset (prefix, list, count):
    if count is 0:
        print prefix
        return
    for i in range (len(list)):
        subset ("%s%s"%(prefix,list[i]), list[i+1:], count - 1)

subset ("", "1234", 3)
```

which outputs, for various values of the input string (second parameter to `subset`):

```
123456   12345   1234   123   12
------   -----   ----   ---   --
123      123     123    123
124      124     124
125      125     134
126      134     234
134      135
135      145
136      234
145      235
146      245
156      345
234
235
236
245
246
256
345
346
356
456
```

Comment: There are subsets missing. E.g. I don't seem to see subset '24'. Example provided by the author of the question does not match the task in bold

Comment: @sasha199568, `24` is *not* a "subset of three elements" since there are only two elements in it. I think you may have misunderstood the question to mean all subsets of a three-element set. What was *actually* asked for was all subsets of size 3, for a given set of size n.

Comment: Yes, maybe I was tired yesterday, didn't notice that there should be subsets of length three

Answer (score 3):

Knuth's fascile 2 from volume 4 has an elegant solution.

http://cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/

Edit: it is fascicle 3A
http://cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc3a.pdf

Comment: Great, how about posting the actual solution or at least linking to it? Otherwise, this is not particularly helpful *as an answer*.

Answer (score 2):

Think recursively. You want subsets of length 3. What I can do is that for all n in subsets I will simply attach all the subsets of length 2 to n. While considering the length 2 I will not consider any elements for 1 to n, as these are already processed. 
S(3,n) = n.S(2,n+1) for all n;

e.g. when n = 1, I will create all the subsets of length 2 with remaining elements. (2,3),(3,4),(2,4). Now attaching 1 I will get (1,2,3),(1,3,4),(1,2,4). I will continue this for 2. Only that for 2 while creating the subsets of length 2 I will not consider 1. So I have only one subset of length 2 (3,4). Attaching this to 2 I get (2,3,4) and combining all I get 
(1,2,3),(1,3,4),(1,2,4),(2,3,4).

Answer (score 1):

I first tried to solve it for the specific case when S = {1,2,3,4} and n=3, but then I decided to just do it for S = a list of m elements and n an arbitrary number>=1. Also, this is my first program in Java :) so I hope u enjoy!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Combinari {

    public static void combinari(int[] array, int n, int[] toPrint){
        if(n==1){
            for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<toPrint.length;j++) System.out.print(toPrint[j]);
                System.out.println(array[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            for(int i=0;i<array.length-n+1;i++){
                int [] newToPrint = Arrays.copyOf(toPrint, toPrint.length+1);
                newToPrint[toPrint.length] = array[i];
                int [] new_array =  Arrays.copyOfRange(array, i+1, array.length);
                combinari(new_array,n-1,newToPrint);
            }
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        int [] iaka={}; // iaka est for printing :)
        combinari(array, 3, iaka);
        System.out.println("");

    }

}
```